# изменится ли первоночальный размер диска С после установки Linux

Tags: linux-mint

Сейчас у меня установлена о/с Windows, один жесткий диск, на котором есть два диска: C и D. Диск С имеет размер 150 432 112 640 байт (140 Гб). Сделан бекап, на диск С. Бекап распложён на съемном носителе. Если изменить размер диска С, то бекап обратно уже НЕ сможет воссоздать диск С. Я хочу установить о/с Linux Mint 19.1. Во время установки будет стерт диск С. Если не понравится Linux, воссоздам обратно Windows. ВОПРОС. Останется ли размер диска С 150 432 112 640 байт (140 Гб) ПРЕЖНИМ или будет произведена переразметка диска С (например, добавлен раздел подкачки за счет размера диска С)? Спасибо.

Comment: То что вы называете дисками C и D является разделами. Никаких дисков C и D в Линукс нет. Ответ вам в принципе уже дали, я лишь уточню, что когда вы будете удалять "диск" (раздел) и на его месте монтировать корневую директорию Линукс в новой файловой системе и новом разделе, то во-первых само пространство расширять или урезать не потребуется - будет использовано столько места, сколько выделите. А во-вторых, даже если на технические нужды потратятся какие-то копейки, то для Линукс-дистрибутивов в большинстве случаев 140 гб - это очень много. Столько не нужно.

Comment: Я лично много лет пользуюсь Xubuntu и у меня под системный раздел выделено 60гб, из которых 50 свободно.

Comment: Уважаемый  Beast Winterwolf! Спасибо Вам большое! Я сделал бэкап диска С (140гб). Я понимаю, что для линукс это много. Но, я не хочу разделять диск С, что бы иметь возможность опять восстановить из бекапа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно будет форматировать диск в файловую систему Extfs, сейчас у Вас NTFS, так что может изменится из-за размера кластера, и прочей служебной информации, но в чём проблема после установки Linux и если:

> не понравится Linux

Создать раздел размером 150 432 112 640 байт? Linux можно посмотреть и не устанавливая... Плюс ко всему можно установить на виртуальную машину! Ок, а почему не сделать Backup тем же Acronis? Ему всё равно размер диска, он его даже на пустом HDD создаст.

Comment: Уважаемый Vadim Pedchenko! Большое Вам спасибо! После обновления (КВ 1807), Windows без всякого предупреждения откусывает, если не ошибаюсь, 40 Мб с диска С для чего-то. После этого, Acronis не смог восстановить бэкап.

Comment: Уважаемый Vadim Pedchenko! Я установил на виртуальную машину для просто посмотреть. Меня интересует, раздел /(корневой), swap(подкачка) и home. Они установятся на диск С или диск С будет разделен на эти разделы, а также будет ли затронут диск D.